# Hoeffding inequality with example

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval, intuition

I am trying to understand Hoeffding inequality, but apart from theory I am not able to understand how we can use it. Can anyone please explain it with an example? Which kind of problem does Hoeffding inequality solve?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding-Ungleichung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A famous use of Hoeffding inequality is to proove regret bounds in bandit problems. The famous UCB algorithm has a bound that can be prooved using this inequality (see e.g. http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/2014fall-cs294stat260/lectures/bandit-ucb-notes.pdf for the proof)